# Is there any way to get the list of classes that exist in a C++ executable?

Tags: c++, class-diagram

I have a C++ executable binary that was compiled from combining many files which has a number of classes defined in them. Is it possible to get a list of classes, methods and properties that are there in it? I might be asking too much but can I somehow also automatically generate a class diagram which is my ultimate goal?

Comment: Can you specify if the code is yours, or if you are trying to do this with a distributed binary?  

If it's yours, consider using doxygen (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) or a similar tool to build a class diagram.

Comment: I am trying to do this in a distributed binary. I wanted see how the classes in the binary is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the executable was compiled with debug symbols, you might have a chance to at least get the class names. On Linux, you'd do

```
nm -C <executable>
```

which should give you a list of symbols. You should read the documentation of `nm`, because it provides quite a bit of information. However, you won't get a class hierarchy. I even believe that would be rather hard. You could try checking which constructors are called by other constructors, maybe you'll get lucky, but that **will** be a mess.

Comment: To clarify `nm -C` 'demangles' the output so that something like:

`U __ZN13TVersionCheckC1Ei`

looks like:

`U TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck`

Not all `nm`s include this flag.  On Mac OS X, use:

`nm [name_of_binary] | c++filt -p -i`

Comment: Sorry, a couple more clarifications: the executable/library doesn't necessarily need to be compiled with debug symbols for this to work.  Also, nm lists only the exported symbols.  It is possible (likely!) that other classes/objects exist that are *not* exported.

Comment: Thanks atleast I can start with something now!
@MikeGM Thank you for further explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can use [nm](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) to get symbols in a library (classes, it's methods and functions).